# svn on GNU/Linux unable to access my repository from remote computer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have running Svn on GNU/Linux. it is working fine when i executing my svn command using Putty on another windows computer. But I am unable to access my svn using Dreamweaver or TortoiseSVN Client.

Error Messages:

Server and project are not accessible! (can't connect to host '192.168.1.10': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Is there any firewal issue? I don't know how to open a 3690 port on linux server? or it is by default open when svn installed? Is there any configuration which i need to do to access svn.

I want to access svn using SVN://Host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

port access was disabled in firewall. I just add the access for svn port. and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

SVN supports multiple protocols for accessing repositories, including HTTP, SSH, and even its own SVN protocol.  Port 3690 is the default port for the SVN protocol. You can specify the protocol to use in the repository URL.  For example. http:// or svn://.

To use ssh, try using something like:
svn+ssh://username@hostname/path/to/repository

Search for "ssh" in TortoiseSVN help for more information.

Comment: I think i have mentioned that I want to use SVN:// method :)

Answer (score 0):

To use svn:// protocol, the svnserve process must be started, either by xinetd or by an init script. In most distros, there should be shipped a file for xinetd, e.g. on SuSE `/etc/xinetd.d/svnserve` where you can comment out the `disable = yes` line an set repositorys directory in `server_args =`.